# to call html embedded applet by urlconnection

Tags: java, applet, urlconnection

I have the following simple embedding applet html page:

```html
<html>
    <applet code="WelcomeApplet.class" archive="WelcomeApplet.jar" width=300 height=30>
    </applet>
</html>
```

If I call for this page (i.e. the address is "`http://192.168.0.2/WelcomeApplet.html`"),
the applet is correctly shown in the browser.

I should call this page only by a servlet because the url page should not be shown, so in the `doGet` servlet method the following code is inserted:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.2/WelcomeApplet.html");    
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();     
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");    
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
conn.setDoInput(true);    
conn.setUseCaches(false);    
conn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);    

BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());    
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    
int byteRead;    
while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1)    
    builder.append((char) byteRead);    
buffer.close();    
out.write(builder.toString());
```

Everything works fine the html parsed is the same as above, but the applet is not shown, the JVM reports : "`WelcomeApplet.class not found`"

It looks like is not a security problem, but an implementation stuff (i guess).

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `code` attribute should name a Java class, not a file. (The JAR file is named by the `archive` attribute.) Thus, the value of the `code` attribute should be just `WelcomeApplet`, assuming it is in the default namespace.

Comment: Also, make sure that you're delivering the JAR correctly and that it contains the compiled applet. Real basic stuff. :-)